# What does $1 [QSA,L] mean in my .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to change my `.htaccess` and there are two lines which I don't understand.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I should use these lines ?

Comment: Read this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463906/how-to-redirect-on-404-php-when-bad-url-is-found

Comment: `htaccess tutorial for beginners` https://helponnet.com/2021/04/15/htaccess-tutorial-for-beginers/

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Not the place to give a complete tutorial, but here it is in short;

[RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) basically means "execute the next RewriteRule only if this is true". The `!-l` path is the condition that the request is not for a link (`!` means not, `-l` means link)

The [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) basically means that if the request is done that matches `^(.+)$` (matches any URL except the server root), it will be rewritten as `index.php?url=$1` which means a request for `olle`will be rewritten as `index.php?url=olle`).

`QSA` means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite (`olle?p=1` will be rewritten as `index.php?url=olle&p=1`.

`L` means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.

For more complete info on this, follow the links above. The rewrite support can be a bit hard to grasp, but there are quite a few examples on stackoverflow to learn from.

Comment: QSA replaces `?` to `&`, making it impossible to distinguish between `/page&foobar` vs `/page?foobar`. How can I stop QSA from replacing `?` to `&`?

Comment: I believe to remember all those things you can make an association like:
`QSA` stands for Query String Append;

`L` stands for last (means execute and  stop looking for the next coincidence)

Comment: -d directory .. -f file

Comment: L is for "last" - while your explanation is perfectly fine, it makes understanding it much easier if you give this memory hint

Answer (score 13):

If the following conditions are true, then rewrite the URL: 
If the requested filename is not a directory,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

and if the requested filename is not a regular file that exists,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

and if the requested filename is not a symbolic link,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

then rewrite the URL in the following way:
Take the whole request filename and provide it as the value of a "url" query parameter to index.php. Append any query string from the original URL as further query parameters (QSA), and stop processing this .htaccess file (L).

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

[Apache docs #flag_qsa](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Another Example:

```
RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [QSA]
```

With the [QSA] flag, a request for

> /pages/123?one=two

will be mapped to

> /page.php?page=123&one=two

Answer (score 0):

This will capture requests for files like `version`,
`release`, and `README.md`, etc. which should be
treated either as endpoints, if defined (as in the
case of /release), or as "not found."