# .htaccess routing PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to write some simple routing in htaccess for PHP

My file looks like this for now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webservices/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server.php [QSA,L]
```

But it does nothing.

The thing that I want with htaccess is that all the calls to server.php are caught like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/webservices/server.php?username=test&password=test
```

to be written

```
http://localhost:8888/webservices/server/u/test/p/test/
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually working, because it redirects all queries to `server.php`. Therefore

```
http://localhost:8888/webservices/server/u/test/p/test/
```

can be handled by `server.php`, where you can easily catch parts of the URI using `explode()` on the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` array. Forget the

```
http://localhost:8888/webservices/server.php?username=test&password=test
```

URL structure, you won't need it anymore, because using the `.htaccess` you've just written, you can dynamically handle every request to your server on `server.php`.

`[QSA]` in your `.htaccess` appends query string to the URI, which is not needed, because we want to get rid of it, right? Since you wont use that format, you can remove `QSA` flag.

Comment: do you have any complete basic url routing in core php tutorial?