# How can I get mod_rewrite to rewrite everything?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I've been trying to achieve is to get my .htaccess file to rewrite ALL URLS.

No matter what I do, however, I cannot get it ignore existing directories. And by that, I mean, act as if they don't exist.

For example, say I have the following file structure:

```
/
    dir1
        file1.php
    dir2
        file2.php
    .htaccess
```

And suppose I want to redirect all traffic to `dir1/file1.php?url=path`.

This never works for me if the path is an existing directory.

For example, if I navigate to `url/path/stuff/dir2`, the "redirecting" works, but the URL in the address bar changes to `url/path/stuff/dir2/?url=dir2` for some unfathomable reason.

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews

Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

# so navigating to a url with a trailing slash won't cause problems
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dir1/file1.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Have you shown us all of your .htaccess?  Do you have a line it that is something like:  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  As it stands, your .htaccess should loop infinitely.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder Ah! That explains many things I didn't understand. But I added a check and it still does not change behavior. (I edited the question though.)

Comment: if you dont want the `?url=dir2` in the address bar but still want to append the data to the `$_GET["url"]`, try removing the `QSA`

Comment: heres two post that I find might related to your problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551382/what-does-1-qsa-l-mean-in-my-htaccess-file

Comment: @Andrew I just don't understand why the address bar is being changed, as I am not doing any redirects. These questions are helpful in understand what the code is doing, but I still cannot understand why the address bar is being changed.

Comment: With `DirectorySlash Off` you won't get trailing slash redirect. Are you sure there is no other .htaccess in your system?

Answer (score 0):

You (updated) .htaccess is saying: IF (it is not an existing file) THEN { rewrite the URL }.  Seems like you want

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dir1/file1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dir1/file1.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In this case, the RewriteCond just prevents infinite looping.  The RewriteRule gets applied once and only once.  Rewrite module will keep cycling thru all the rules until a cycle does not result in a changed to the URI.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This also makes things clearer. But the main problem still persists: navigating to `path/dir2` makes the address bar change to `path/dir2/?url=dir2` while I don't want it to change. (It still "shows" `dir1/file1.php` though, so that's good.)

Comment: Did you try it?  Rewriting to have url=dir2 is done internally to Apache only and shouldn't show up in the browser address bar (unless you actually redirect to that, which you are not doing since you don't have [QSA,L,R]).  All framework use this trick to invoke their front-end controllers to initially handle requests of all forms.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying all sorts of different variations, but the address bar always changes to `path/dir2/?url=dir2`.

Comment: So I did some logging, and there is one line that seems to be the error, this appears in the logs: `split uri=dir1/file1.php?url=dir2 -> uri=dir1/file1.php, args=url=dir2&url=dir2` and I don't understand why.