# Rewrite QSA, understanding it better

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

So, I'm having a difficult time understanding QSA. Since

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L,B]
```

Both give me the same result. I read that QSA appends any parameters passed (at least I think that's what I understood from it). However it's not exactly working for me.

Currently I have the url

```
http://localhost:8888/search/hey+i%27m+a+search+query&SortBy=day
```

which returns

```
hey i'm a search query&SortBy=day
```

I can set it to

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)&SortBy=(.*)$ search.php?s=$1&SortBy=$2 [NC,L,B,QSA]
```

which will successfully return the get parameter, but I from what I understand about the QSA, it should be automatically handled...right?

I got my information from here -
[What does $1 [QSA,L] mean in my .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551382/what-does-1-qsa-l-mean-in-my-htaccess-file)

Basically, my question is, why should I use QSA? And what kind of benefits would it provide in this situation?
(Sorry for being blunt, but I can't get a good grasp of this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your example URL has no query string. You use `?` to designate the query string:

```
http://localhost:8888/search/hey+i%27m+a+search+query?SortBy=day
```

The `?SortBy=day` will be automatically appended to the rewritten query string through the `QSA` flag.

Comment: Ah, thanks man. I was thinking SortBy would be the second GET parameter but since the search query is written into the rewrite rule SortBy is considered the first rule, right?

Comment: No problem. SortBy is not the first query parameter after the rewrite. The reason you need to use `?` is because otherwise .htaccess sees no query string. It does all the merging on it's own, but if it doesn't see it in the first place, it has nothing to merge to.

Comment: Ah okay, so placement doesn't really matter here it's just declaring that there are GET parameters that need handling. Thank you!