# Regex to append a variable to URLs

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a regex right now on a WordPress site using Redirection plugin:

Source URL:
`^/video/(.+)`

Target URL:
`/video/$1`

And that's working fine. Now, I need to add `?filter=views` to the end of the *Target URL*, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

**Desired redirection would be:**

`site.com/video/video-category-name` to `site.com/video/video-category-name?filter=views`

Adding `/video/$1?filter=views` as Target URL adds multiple `?filter=views` when I just need the variable added once.

Any one that can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Target URL = `/video/$1?filter=views` does not work ?

Comment: @stej4n my bad, with the description I added it does work. However what I am trying to do apart from that, is to redirect `/video/whatever-keywords` to `/video/whatever-keywords?filter=views`, and that doesn't work (it adds multiple `?filter=views` after the URL and I just need one). I updated the original question with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude multiple redirections by using

Source URL: `^/video/([^?]+)`

Target URL: `/video/$1?filter=views`

**Explanation**

if Source URL is `^/video/(.+)` then `(.+)` will match anything after `/video/` including after the first redirection :

`/test` match `.+` => REDIRECT TO `/video/test?filter=views`

`/test?filter=views` match `.+` => REDIRECT TO `/video/test?filter=views?filter=views`

... etc.

If you allow any character except `?` after `/video/` then redirection will stop immediately because `/video/$1?filter=views` won't match Source URL anymore

Comment: For some reason the plugin is deleting everything after `?` in Source URL after I hit save.

Comment: By the way, other filter URLs should work (?filter=rating, ?filter=new). I need that when you visit the URL without a filter it adds `?filter=views` by default.

Comment: I added `([^?]+)` (without # as per your recent edit, and it's still adding multiple variables to the URL)

Comment: if the plugin is deleting everything after `?` then it's logical and it redirects again and again. Which plugin are you using ? Maybe it has an option to keep URL args ?

Comment: It seems Wordpress Redirection plugin does not handle query parameters. You should use .htaccess instead and [QSA] flag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551382/what-does-1-qsa-l-mean-in-my-htaccess-file

Comment: Im using WordPress Redirection yes. I tried using .htaccess with this, and it's doing nothing:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/video/([^?]+) /video/$1?filter=views [QSA,L]`

Comment: As query parameters is optional in Redirection plugin or .htaccess, I don't think it's possible to redirect a base URL (with query parameters or not) to the same one without loop. But maybe I'm wrong. Could'nt `views` be your default filter instead to prevent this kind of redirection ?