# combining rewrite rules in htaccess stops access to $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

Before I start, let me say that I have done quite a bit of research to figure this out, but I don't think I know enough about the question to find the solution.

In my `.htaccess` I have a rewrite rule to send my wildcard subdomain to `portal/index.php` with the subdomain as a get parameter.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule .* /portal/index.php?sub_access=%1 [L]
```

This works perfectly, except for the fact I can no longer use `$_GET` variables in my script. If I visit `portal.mywebsite.com/login/?reset`, using `var_dump()` always produces `array(1) { ["sub_access"]=> string(6) "portal" }`

Is there a way to append `$_GET` variables to the generated one in my .htaccess? I'm sure I could do a work around of creating my own get variable capture by scraping the url, but I would much rather just not lose access to this feature.

```
I <3 $_GET
```

Comment: Use QSA to pass query string arguments

Comment: To those visiting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551382/what-does-1-qsa-l-mean-in-my-htaccess-file

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468098/what-is-l-in-qsa-l-in-htaccess @SpencerMay which the answer in there explains what the QSA means; I feel the answer given below should have explained it and for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteRule .* /portal/index.php?sub_access=%1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule .* /portal/index.php?sub_access=%1 [L,QSA]
```

To append then remaining query string.